# angular 5 right router link for my components

Tags: angular, angular5

i have two component in dashboard module 
it is my module routing.ts file i want to have right route to each component in browser ... for example i expect when i click `add` in admin component i
go to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/admin/add` and when in superuser component i click add i go to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/superuser/add`

this moment when click `add` in admin component i see `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/superuser/add`when i expect to see `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/admin/add` ... how can i fix this issue?

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard', component: ProfileComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard/superuser', component: SuperuserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: FormComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'video',
        component: VideoviewComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'add/:upload',
        component: FormComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'view',
        component: ViewComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: EditComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'discount',
        component: DiscountComponent,
      }


    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard/admin', component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: FormComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'video',
        component: VideoviewComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'add/:upload',
        component: FormComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'view',
        component: ViewComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: EditComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'discount',
        component: DiscountComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class DashboardRouting {
}
```

i have 2 seprate compoenent in dashboard module each of them have same below code in thier component.html file:

```
 <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" routerLink="add">add</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" routerLink="view">view all</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" routerLink="video">your video</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on dashboard.

Your route is

```
domain.com/dashboard.
```

In your component, you have thos router links.

```
<a href="#" routerLink="add">add</a> --> domain.com/add
<a href="#" routerLink="view">view all</a> --> domain.com/view
<a href="#" routerLink="video">your video</a> --> domain.com/video
```

If you want to go to the correct route, use the correct routing

```
<a href="#" routerLink="admin/add">add</a>
OR
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['admin', 'add']">add</a>
```

Comment: i did but my url will change automatically why ?

Comment: Then change your routing, that's up to you to show what is displayed

Comment: :D i dont know how can i explain it to you

Comment: With words maybe :P

Comment: we have ```<a href="#" routerLink="product/add">```in admin component when we click it we expect to 
``` path: 'dashboard/admin', component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'product/add',
        component: FormComponent,
      },```
 that click refer to this in routing.ts file . correct ?

Comment: Yes and no : remove the href from your link. Otherwise, yes, it refers to that.

Comment: i did it work correctly . but browser say 
```
core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/superuser/add'
```
in console

Comment: i dont have any thing like that in html link or routing.ts

Comment: Please give me the routerLink of the button that triggers this error

Comment: the error will show when in click this

```
<a  routerLink="product/add">add</a>
```

in admin component

Comment: If your error states `'dashboard/superuser/add`, I highly doubt this is the same button.

Comment: each component have same html code but their routerLink are diffrent

Comment: Look, you don't tell me everything every time, so let's get to the point : your routes aren't defined. You must define them accordingly. This error is very precise, and it means exactly that. Redo your routes correctly, and you should have no more issue.

Comment: its around 3 hour that im doing this :D 
thanks anyway :P

Comment: I understand your frustration, but I can't do anything for you at this point, this is up to you to make correct routes !